# how to open a file in user's home folder

Tags: c++, linux

i'd like to put a kind of lock file in the user's home directory on linux(from c++) but fopen'ing ~/.fluudit doesn't seem to work.

```
fopen("~/.fluudit","w");   //fails
```

Comment: ~ doesn't work here because it is the shell that translates ~ to appropriate home directory. The shell replaces the special character (~) in the command line to absolute path. Hence ~ cannot be used in C or C++ programs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `HOME` and if that's not present, you can use the password database:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());

const char *homedir = pw->pw_dir;
```

Answer (score 7):

The expansion of `~` to, say, `getenv("HOME")` is called globbing and is something you need to do first.  You didn't say which libaries or frameworks you are using, but some provide this.