# Segmentation core error c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, serial-port, serial-communication

I am little bit ruggy with C coding, but I need this script working to test serial communication with a microcontroller. I have the following code written as:

```
int main() {

char *portname = "/dev/ttyACM0";
FILE *csv = fopen("~/Desktop/my.csv", "wb");

int fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
if (fd < 0)
{
        //error_message ("error %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror (errno));
        return 1;
}

set_interface_attribs (fd, B9600, 0);  // set speed to 9600 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
set_blocking (fd, 1);                // set no blocking

char a = 255;
int i = 0;

write(fd, &a, 1);

do {
  char c;
  read(fd, &c, 1); // wait for next value
  fprintf(csv, "%d\n", c);
  i ++;
} while(i < 10000); //keep running this loop for a while

write(fd, &a, 1);
fclose(csv);
close(fd);
return 0;
```

This scripts should connect successfully for serial communication, send a start bit (255) to the receiver which operates some actions, and then start writing received data on csv file until the while loop ends up. Have compiled that source with the instruction:

```
g++ -o serial c-serial.c
```

where c-serial.c is the name of the source code. Just skip the two "set" function, they are visible in this scope so the error comes not out of this. In fact, when executing I receive:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You didn't check whether `fopen` worked for the CSV file.

Comment: First of all build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building). Then learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens.

Comment: No, I didn't, do you think that's the reason? @Mat

Comment: You're the only one that can find out, @LiukPet.

Comment: This code compiles, the error is showed during execution time! @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Except for the call to `open` you don't check for *any* error. Not only `fopen` can fail, but `read`, `write` and `fprintf` as well. Technically `close` can also fail, but nobody ever checks for it.

Comment: I know. but to be able to learn *where* it fail you need to use a debugger, *and* to build with debug information (which will save things like file names, function names, and line numbers) which is needed for the debugger to tell you the exact location in your source where the crash happens.

Comment: Please do not use C++ front to compile C programs... :D

Comment: I am a newby here, deal w/ it :) @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function call [fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) is not able to resolve `~` as your home directory. Please take a look at [how to open a file in user's home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2924289/2429333).

Answer (score 0):

In your fprintf statement you tell the programm to print an integer (usually two bytes) but provide a char variable (one byte) to print from. fprintf relies on the supplied format string to decide how many bytes to read from the source. In this case fprintf tries to read (at least) two bytes from a one-byte-memory block. Therefore fprintf will try to access memory which might not even be allocated to the program, producing a segmentation fault.

Correct the format string to print a character only.
For more information on fprintf and format strings see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm).